# Correct way to send JSON DATA via POST php

Tags: php, curl, json

Is the correct way to send `$json` data via `CURL`? in PHP,

I have my `$json` data in one php, I can send the data information via `POST` using `CURL` to my api,??

Do you have some examples, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find before post:
http://bavotasan.com/2011/post-url-using-curl-php/

In some key on $data, put your $json.

Example

```
function post_to_url($url, $data) {
   $fields = '';
   foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
      $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
   }
   rtrim($fields, '&');

   $post = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

   $result = curl_exec($post);

   curl_close($post);
}

    $json = json_encode($your_json); //Your json data
$data = array(
   "name" => "c.bavota",
   "website" => "http://bavotasan.com",
   "twitterID" => "bavotasan",
       "json" => $json
);

post_to_url("http://yoursite.com/post-to-page.php", $data);
```

Comment: mmmm all in the same page right? and the only when i refresh the page should be send the data???

Comment: But the problem is $jsondata = json_encode($json); no fetch my data the curl, is like my json doen't have nothing, when i refresh the page i got the response of the server and say, no data, but if i make echo json_encode ($json); i got the strings

Comment: I updated my answer. Try it. After post try get json. `echo $_POST['json']`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do.

Eg.

```
// $json_string : Your json String
    $ch = curl_init('http://api.example.com/post');                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_string))                                                                       
    );                                                                                                                   

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: But the problem is $jsondata = json_encode($json); no fetch my data the curl, is like my json doen't have nothing, when i refresh the page i got the response of the server and say, no data, but if i make echo json_encode ($json); i got the strings

Comment: @Jeson M John, you mean if i get the output of the json? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333828/send-json-data-php-via-curl/21333968?noredirect=1#comment32224252_21333968 here i put more information please help me :)

Comment: @Deimos From where do you create `json` data?

Comment: @Deimos Reply fast if you can. I would love to help. Else You'll get delayed replies!

Comment: @Deimos Couldn't load that site. Just send code to jenson555@gmail.com

Comment: i sent you the file php :)